# wrong data type in packet layer (scapy)

Tags: python-2.7, layer, scapy, packet

I want to reconstruct a packet with scapy. If I compare the original packet with my constructed packet, I see that a few entries in a layer of my packet have the wrong values. I think it comes from unsuitable datatypes of some values like the following one:

If I print *stream_id* in one string like this

```
stream_id = "\x00\x22\x97\x04\x06\xba\x00\x00"
```

the output is unreadable (like wingding symbols).

But if I put *stream_id* together myself like this

```
alias = "CB"
stream_id = '\\x' + alias + '\\x' + alias + '\\x' + alias + '\\x' + alias
```

the printing output is **\x9B\x9B\x9B\x9B**.

What's the difference between those two notations?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x<hex_byte>` is a special escape sequence for Python strings denoting a literal byte as a hex digit.

The first one is essentially writing bytes to your `stream_id`, e.g.:

```
stream_id_1 = "\x00\x22\x97\x04\x06\xba\x00\x00"
stream_id_2 = chr(0x00) + chr(0x22) + chr(0x97) + chr(0x04) \
              + chr(0x06) + chr(0xba) + chr(0x00) + chr(0x00)

assert stream_id_1 == stream_id_2  # passes
```

and if you print out the bytes you get: `0022970406ba0000`

While the second one is writing a string, as if you wrote (using the same data as above):

```
stream_id_1 = "\\x00\\x22\\x97\\x04\\x06\\xba\\x00\\x00"
```

escaping the escape sequence so that the numbers don't get interpreted as bytes, resulting in the following printout: `5c7830305c7832325c7839375c7830345c7830365c7862615c7830305c783030` which is, as you can see, a vastly different structure.

**UPDATE** - To build a stream of bytes you can construct them as in the 'manually' built string - by converting your `alias` to an integer and then using `chr()` to turn it into a byte char:

```
alias = chr(int("CB", 16))
stream_id = alias + alias + alias + alias  # etc.
```

But judging by your comment, you just want to get a random byte so don't waste cycles by generating a hex string, then turning it into an integer to finally turn it into a byte char - get a random integer immediately and turn it into a byte char:

```
alias = chr(random.randint(0, 255))
stream_id = alias + alias + alias + alias  # etc.
```

Or even better, forgo the `random` module and use `os.urandom()` instead:

```
import os

alias = os.urandom(1)
stream_id = alias + alias + alias + alias  # etc.
```

Of course, you can use the same technique to get as many different random bytes as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I want to write bytes to my stream_id variable, but not fixed like this **stream_id_1 = "\x00\x22\x97\x04\x06\xba\x00\x00"**.
I want to put together the numbers in the stream_id variable at myself like this **(1)alias = (''.join(random.choice(string.hexdigits) for _ in range(2))) (2)stream_id = ... + alias + ... + alias + ... + alias + ... + alias**